# Deep search of several pdf files with pdfgrep, ignoring counts less than

Tags: pdfgrep

I am doing a "deep search" within several pdf files with "pdfgrep", trying to find a word and get a count on the documents like this:

```
# pdfgrep -ric PATTERN

./Example1.pdf:0
./Example2.pdf:10
```

Any idea how i can ignore the printout for files with an defined number of counts? Like 0 or less than...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming file paths don't contain newline characters, you can just pipe that output to:

```
grep -v ':0$'
```

To filter out the lines ending in `:0`.

Or

```
awk -F: '$NF >= 10'
```

To only list the files with at least 10 matches.

To handle arbitrary file paths including those with newline characters, use NUL delimiters:

```
pcregrep -ricZ pattern | gawk -v RS='\0' '
  {RS="\n"; getline count; RS="\0"}
  count > 0 {print $0":"count}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)